# Defining specific evaluation task to specific parallel kernel

Tags: parallelization

Is it possible to specify particular task to a particular kernel to be evaluated in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
krs=LaunchKernels[]; (*It launches 6 kernels by default on my PC*)

ParallelEvaluate[a = 1 + 1, krs[[5]]];

ParallelEvaluate[Names["a"]]
```

The output is like:

{{}, {}, {}, {}, {"a"}, {}}

Comment: What I am looking for is to evaluate two expressions with each executed on different kernel in parallel. For example, I want to evaluate 1+1 on kernel 1, and 2+2 on kernel 2.

Comment: @SleekTitan, I understood. Try `ParallelEvaluate` as I shown with corresponding second argument for choosing the kernel. The `krs[[5]]` means the fifth one.